# How to get a list of backstack fragment entries in android?

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, back-stack

I'm working on an application in which tabs are implemented using `FragmentActivity`. Since, tabs are required throughout the application, fragments are used extensively to make the application compatible on all the versions of android.

As a consequence, I'm facing a problem in visualizing as to what fragments are present on the backstack. I'm sure there is a **way to retrieve the list of fragments present on the backstack**. Thanks.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) has methods:

**getBackStackEntryCount()**

**getBackStackEntryAt (int index)**

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

for(int entry = 0; entry<fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++){
   Log.i(TAG, "Found fragment: " + fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getId());
}
```

Comment: getId returns the id of backstack not the fragment

Comment: Downvote because this is wrong. If you execute `findFragmentById()` and use these ids, you will not find a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved logging of fragments in the back stack with this code (in Kotlin):

```
findNavController().backQueue.forEach {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.destination}")
    }
```

This code iterates through every entry in the navigation back stack, printing out the destination name of the Fragment.

Comment: Hi backQueue doesn't exist ?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to check which fragment is visible and if you know the id of view where fragment is placed, first you have to add below in onCreate()

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onBackStackChanged() {
    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if (f != null){
      updateActionBarTitle(f);
    }

  }
});

private void updateActionBarTitle(Fragment fragment) {
        String fragClassName = fragment.getClass().getName();

        if (fragClassName.equals(FirstFragment.class.getName())) {
            setTitle("Home");
        } else if (fragClassName.equals(SecondFragment.class.getName())) {
            setTitle("Second");
        }
    }
```

This will update your action bar title on back stack change listener.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question asked?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the question asked.